# Mapping huggingface tokens to original input text

Tags: tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

How can I map the tokens I get from huggingface `DistilBertTokenizer` to the positions of the input text?

e.g. `I have a new GPU` -> `["i", "have", "a", "new", "gp", "##u"]` -> `[(0, 1), (2, 6), ...]`

I'm interested in this because suppose that I have some attention values assigned to each token, I would like to show which part of the original text it actually corresponds to, since the tokenized version is not non-ML people friendly.

I have not found any solution to this yet especially when there is `[UNK]` token. Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about character mappings? Do you necessarily have to show each individual (subword) token, or would it be an alternative to average over subwords and merge them back together (e.g., averaging over `gp` and `##u`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions of Transformers (it seems like since 2.8), calling the tokenizer returns an object of class [`BatchEncoding`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#batchencoding) when methods `__call__`, `encode_plus` and `batch_encode_plus` are used. You can use method [`token_to_chars`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.BatchEncoding.token_to_chars) that takes the indices in the batch and returns the character spans in the original string.

Comment: Just a note, [`encode_plus` is now deprecated](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.2/en/internal/tokenization_utils#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.encode_plus), and `__call__` should be used instead (that is rather than doing `tokenizer.encode_plus("My input string")`, do `tokenizer("My input string")`; it returns a BatchEncoding object which has the method `token_to_chars`).